# C tricky program

Tags: c, macros, printf, scanf

my teacher gave me this program for assignment. I did my assignment but cant understood why this output came. can you please explain this prog. or output.
#include<stdio.h>
#define scanf "%sABCDE"

```
int main(){
  printf(scanf,scanf);
  return 0;
}
```

Output-

```
-->./main
-->%sABCDEABCDE
```

Comment: If your teacher is giving you such assignments, you need a new teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#define` replaces the `scanf` to `"ABCDE"` this value. #define is used when you want to define the value to a specific variable for example
you can define the value of pi as 3.15
`#define pi 3.14` now in the whole program if you use `pi` variable then it will take 3.14 value. so according to your program first `scanf` is a string and in printf first argument is the type of variable so it's the string type or you can say an array of characters since C doesn't support string so it is printing `%s` then the second argument is the variable itself and it's printing the value of the `scanf`.

Comment: Then why it is not %sABCDE %sABCDE  , why %s didn't printed out twice.

Comment: @sumitpatil do you know why printf(%d", 5) is printing 5 not %d5?

Comment: because %d is for int it place the value..am I right?

Comment: yes @sumitpatil if the value is of type int.

Comment: @youcantseeme then  isn't output should be ABCDEABCDE rather than %sABCDEABCDE.  I mean why the %s?

Comment: @sumitpatil Do you understand why `printf("%s", "%s")` would print `%s`?

Comment: NO plz enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are just text replacement (info for nitpickers: I know about tokens). Macros are processed before compilation (thus term preprocessing),

The compiler is compiling the code after all the macros are replaced:

```
int main(){
  printf("%sABCDE","%sABCDE");
  return 0;
}
```

I think that now everything is clear.

Comment: Then why it is not %sABCDE %sABCDE  , why %s didn't printed out twice. but only once.?

Comment: because %s means print string which is `%sABCDE` so it prints `%sABCDE` and then what is left after the %s in the fist parameter. You need to learn about `printf`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define macro "%sABCDE"

int main(){
  printf(macro,macro);
  return 0;
}
```

becomes

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("%sABCDE","%sABCDE");
  return 0;
}
```

The first argument to printf is the format string, while the second argument is another string (const char*)

Comment: Then why it is not %sABCDE %sABCDE  , why %s didn't printed out twice.but only once.?